# Wordpress Gallery shortcode with pagination

Tags: pagination, gallery

I would like to make simple gallery with pagination. I use this shortcode
[gallery category="food"] I added an override to the function.php but the pagination not working. Listing all attachments. I'd like to list only 18 on one page. "post_per_page" param unfortunately not working. Here is my code.

```
        // GALLERY

        function my_gallery($html, $attr)
        {
            $post = get_post();

            if (!empty($attr['ids'])) {
                if (empty($attr['orderby']))
                    $attr['orderby'] = 'post__in';
                $attr['include'] = $attr['ids'];
            }

            if (isset($attr['orderby'])) {
                $attr['orderby'] = sanitize_sql_orderby($attr['orderby']);
                if (!$attr['orderby'])
                    unset($attr['orderby']);
            }

            extract(shortcode_atts(array(
                'order' => 'ASC',
                'orderby' => 'date',
                'id' => $post ? $post->ID : 0
            ), $attr, 'gallery'));

            $paged       = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
            $attachments = get_posts(array(
                'include' => $include,
                'posts_per_page' => 18,
                'paged' => $paged,
                'post_status' => 'inherit',
                'post_type' => 'attachment',
                'post_mime_type' => 'image',
                'order' => $order,
                'orderby' => $orderby
            ));
            foreach ($_attachments as $key => $val) {
                $attachments[$val->ID] = $attachments[$key];
            }
            $html .= '<div class="mansory">';
            foreach ($attachments as $id => $attachment) {
                $html .= '<div class="mansory-item"><figure>';
                $html .= '<img data-img="' . wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID, 'Large') . '" src="' . wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID, 'M') . '" alt="' . get_post_meta($attachment->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true) . '" title="' . get_post_meta($attachment->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true) . '" />';
                $html .= '<figcaption>' . $id->post_content;
                $html .= '</figcaption></figure></figure></div>';
            }
            $html .= '</div>';

            // Gallery Pagination

            $img_num  = count(get_posts(array(
                'post_type' => 'attachment',
                'include' => $include,
                'posts_per_page' => -1
            )));
            $img_page = count($attachments);
            if ($img_num % $img_page == 0) {
                $pages = $img_num / $img_page;
            } else {
                $pages = $pages = ($img_num / $img_page) + 1;
            }

            if ($img_page > $img_num) {
                $html .= "<div id='pagination'><ul>";
                if ($paged > 1) {
                    $html .= "<li class='prev'>
                                    <a href='?paged=" . ($paged - 1) . "'></a>
                                </li>";
                }
                for ($i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++) {

                    if ($paged == $i) {
                        $html .= "<li class='selected'><a href='?paged=" . $i . "'";
                    } else {
                        $html .= "<li><a href='?paged=" . $i . "'";
                    }

                    $html .= ">" . $i . "</a></li>";
                }
                if ($paged < $pages) {
                    $html .= "<li class='next'>
                                    <a href='?paged=" . ($paged + 1) . "'></a>
                                </li>";
                }

                $html .= "</ul></div>";
            }
            return $html;
        }
        add_filter("post_gallery", "my_gallery", 10, 2);
```